# Visualizing queue length with colored Polylines - Folium

Tags: python, folium

I have a bunch of PolyLines that i want to color code based on the length. 
I managed to change the color of the entire line, based on the length of a line segment (between 2 of 6 points), but I am having trouble figuring out how to color parts of the line instead of the entire line.

I am to visualize queue lengths, so I want to change the color of each line/queue based on the length, so if shorter than 5 m = green, 5-10 m = yellow, >10 m = red.

What I've done so far is:

```
def color_length(x):
    if x < 0:
        raise ValueError
    elif 0 < x < 5:
        return "green"
    elif 5 < x < 10:
        return "yellow"
    else:
        return "red"
```

And then I put it into:

`folium.PolyLine(points, 'color_length(x)', weight=2.5, opacity=1).add_to(mymap)`

But as mentioned, when doing this, it returns only one color for entire line, and not for the segment, which the "def" refers to.

Comment: Why are you passing the function inside a string? Assuming `x` is already defined somewhere in your program and that your function works fine, removing the quotes around it should work as it will return the string with the color you want. `folium.PolyLine(points, color_length(x), weight=2.5, opacity=1).add_to(mymap)`

Comment: i don't know why I did that, but I changed it after posting my question.. But I still need help with getting different colors on the line

Comment: What's `x` on your code? Can you post a bigger protion of your code? Not necessarily everything you have written but a Minimal Working Example that helps people answer your question.

Comment: Sure. x is the distance between two points:

def calculateDistance(x1,y1,x2,y2):  
     dist = math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)  
     return dist  

x = calculateDistance(x1,y1,x2,y2)